# Search with synonym letters for arabic language

Tags: wordpress

How can I have WordPress search different letters in Arabic?

How can I have WordPress search different letters in Arabic?

For example, أ-ا-إ are the same letters but in different formats.

E.g. can I search WordPress for something like "world" > "?orld" (using REGEX or similar)?